# jQuery - Draggable item html style bug + Revert to original container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

### I want to:

- Make the draggable element drop in a container.
- Change the elements html when dropped.
- When the dropped element is dragged outside the container, revert to the original position and also revert to old html.

### My current problems

- While the draggable element is hovering the container, it already changes its style.
- I can't understand how can I achieve 'dropped element revert to original position' (point 3 @ "I want to")

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/27Hqj/1/

HTML

```
<div class="draggable-items">
    <div class="main-groups">Item 1</div>
    <div class="main-groups">Item 2</div>
    <div class="main-groups">Item 3</div>
    <div class="main-groups">Item 4</div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $( ".main-groups" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#container",
        helper: "original",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $( "#container" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var html = [];
            $(this).find('.main-groups').each(function() {
                html.push('<div class="main-groups"><b><a href="#'+$(this).attr("id")+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a></b></div>');
            });
            $(this).find('.main-groups').replaceWith(html.join(''));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an easier time using connected sortable lists, like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/27Hqj/2/)**

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable-items").sortable({
        connectWith: "#container",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-sortable-helper').outerWidth($(".draggable-items").innerWidth()).css('background', '#333');
        }
    });

    $("#container").sortable({
        connectWith: ".draggable-items",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-sortable-helper').outerWidth($("#container").innerWidth()).css('background', 'blue');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that when hovering on the container, and because it was set to 100%, it changed the width to fit the container.

To fix it I modified it to this:

```
$( ".main-groups" ).draggable({
     connectToSortable: "#accordion2",
     helper: "original",
     revert: "invalid",
     start : function(event, ui) {
         ui.helper.width($(this).width());
     } 
});
```

This doesn't let the draggable item change its width while hovering the container. It changes its width when dropped onto it.

But I still havn't managed to figure out how could I remove dropped elements in the container to the original placeholder.